# how to add CAShapeLayer having transparent png image using clip path?

Tags: ios, core-graphics, quartz-core, cashapelayer

I have transparent png image of star shape. How can i add this transparent image into CAShapeLayer using clip path and add this path for change in ShapeLayer.

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show some code or an attempt at solving this problem.

Comment: https://pastee.org/d6e8c

Comment: Can't access your code @user38726...